# A pivot table may have more fields than just Ids

Tags: mysql, database-design, many-to-many, relational-database

I have two tables that I need to connect:  `discipline` and `class`.
It will be a N:N relation, so I'll create a new table `class_discipline`.

Does my pivot table `class_discipline` may have more fields than just the `Ids` of the two tables ? Is it a good practice ?
If yes, is there some kind of rule that I should follow to do such a thing ?

Let me explain the situation:  I'll import some data from an excel file, I can't change the data of this file (My university provides it).
And this file have some data that does not fit neither on `discipline` or  `class` tables. So I guess I should insert this "extra data" into the pivot table.

Comment: @jso Please, read the link you posted. It's not what I'm asking or my situation.

Comment: I meant primarily the answers in that thread. Though with the question update it now looks a bit different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table `class_discipline` can have as many columns as you want.

Generally any column in that junction table represents an attribute of the relationship. In this case if a relationship between `class` ad `discipline` needs any specification then yes, use more columns.

Example:

Assume you have tables `students` and `courses`. And to define who is enrolled in which course, you will create `student_course` table containing only `student_id` and `course_id`. But if you want to know when a student enrolled, you need to save this information somewhere (it's not an attribute of a `student` nor `course`). That's the time for adding new column into `student_course` table.

Good or bad practice?

Using additional columns in a junction table for attributes of the relationship is a good practice normally. However you need to keep in mind that you lose the column values if the relationship is removed.

Additional comments:

- If you are using such structure in an application or via ORM, note that plain `N:N` relationship is a field of a class. Once you need more attributes of the relationship you need to have a separate class.

Comment: But isn't this a "bad practice" ? I'm trying to find the best way to do things.

Comment: No, it's a good practice normally. Will update the answer once more.